# How to read a json file and transcribe it

Tags: arrays, json, xamarin.forms

I imported this json file into the project, and as you can see it is a vector

```
    {
   "objArray": [
      {
         "min_position": 4,
         "has_more_items": false,
         "items_html": "Bike",
         "new_latent_count": 7
      },
      {
         "min_position": 9,
         "has_more_items": false,
         "items_html": "Car",
         "new_latent_count": 8
      },
      {
         "min_position": 9,
         "has_more_items": false,
         "items_html": "Bus",
         "new_latent_count": 8
      },
      {
         "min_position": 3,
         "has_more_items": true,
         "items_html": "Car",
         "new_latent_count": 1
      },
      {
         "min_position": 3,
         "has_more_items": false,
         "items_html": "Bus",
         "new_latent_count": 9
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to ask if there was a way to read it all and transcribe it to xamarin

Answer (score 0):

using [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
```

from [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com)

```
public class ObjArray
{
    public int min_position { get; set; }
    public bool has_more_items { get; set; }
    public string items_html { get; set; }
    public int new_latent_count { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<ObjArray> objArray { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, then if I want to write the content inside the labels what can I do?

Comment: Assign the `Text` property of the Label.  Or use data binding.  There are many ways you could do it

Comment: I don't understand where it gets "myJsonResponse", I create a string variable and assign it as a value the name I gave to the json file inside the project, but it gives me an error

Comment: that's a string containing the json data.  If you have it as a file in your project you will need to read it into a string variable first